# Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

Tags: kotlin

Getting below errors for same file and on same line.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but TypeVariable(V) was expected
```

This is the code:

```
return posLevelRealizedFxGlRecords.filter {
      if (it == null) {
        false
      } else {
        var bookCurrency: String? = bookIdToBookCurrencyMap.getOrPut(it.bookId) {
          val book: Book? = dataLookupService.getBook(it.bookId, knowledgeTimestamp)
          book?.p?.bookCurrencyId
        }

        if (bookCurrency == null) {
          false
        } else {
          it.currencyId != bookCurrency
        }
      }
    }
```

Showing those errors on below line.

```
book?.p?.bookCurrencyId
```

I tried below code as well instead of above line,

```
if (book == null) {
            null
          } else {
            book.p.bookCurrencyId
          }
```

Can you please help to resolve these errors ?

Comment: What is the type of `bookIdToBookCurrencyMap`?

Comment: What should your filter return if `book` is null?  (Or if `book.p` is null, if that's possible?  Or `book.p.bookCurrencyId`?)

Comment: if book is null it should return null. book.p null is not possible.

Comment: @Nitrodon It's mutableMapOf<String, String>()

Comment: If [`getOrPut()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html) doesn't find that key in the map, it calls the lambda to get a default value *and sets that value in the map*.  But your map has non-nullable values, so how could it set a null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [getOrPut](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html) signature, the `defaultValue` parameter should return a `String` in your case, but you are returning a nullable `String` (`String?`), hence the compilation error.

Either you should change `bookIdToBookCurrencyMap` to `mutableMapOf<String, String?>` or return a non-nullable `String` like:

```
....
book?.p?.bookCurrencyId?:"NOT_FOUND" // you can return whatever you want to express null value for bookCurrencyId
....
```